# Using HttpClient in android studio

Tags: php, android, http, android-studio

I'm trying to Post some data to a PHP script from my android application, all the [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21372276/how-to-pass-a-value-from-android-to-php-web-service-and-retrieve-it) I can find suggest using HTTPClient however the example code as shown below clearly doesn't work, am I missing something?

[image: Error]

Comment: I have the same exact issue :(

Answer (score 2):

Apache HTTP Client was deprecated in Android 5.1 and removed in Android 6.0

[Apache HTTP Client Removal](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)

So as they say use HttpUrlConnection instead

[HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

You can also use a high level api like [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) or other networking http librairies

Comment: Ok, but currently I have put the values into a keyValuePair list, how do i implement this with the httpUrlConnection? or should the values be stored a different way?

Comment: This will be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767952/how-to-add-parameters-to-httpurlconnection-using-post