# How to use HttpClient in android studio app?

Tags: android-studio, httpclient

unfortunately [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33576637/using-httpclient-in-android-studio) was closed however it is spot on.  Let me go through the steps as I am reproducing a legacy app issue that uses httpclient so switching is not an option YET (6 months out maybe).

1. create android studio app
2. try to use Httpclient and as he shows in the post above it is in red
3. I try to add this line in build.gradle to bring it in as a work around(even though core android also brings it in)

   implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13'

Then I get this error in android studio

```
`httpclient` defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for `httpclient` use `HttpUrlConnection` or `okhttp` instead), or repackaging the library using something like `jarjar`.
```

Ok, so I am using the wrong version so I run build scan and I see this so I bring this one in instead of the other version (android studio now sees HttpClient and can import it at this point)

[image]

I still get the same error though about conflicting android libs.

**QUESTION: How do I fix the red in my legacy project and not have this error either?**

My best bet seems to ignore the error.  Will I have issues that I am not seeing though in the future?